# mongoDB geospatial query doesn't works

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

I'm trying to extract all the elements inside a polygon (regular or irregular) but mongoDB geospatial doesn't works.

When I do the query like this, works perfectly

```
db.getCollection('houses').find({
  'coordinates_geojson.coordinates.1': {
        '$lte': 20.49584842128357,
        '$gte': 20.458539491985142
    },
    'coordinates_geojson.coordinates.0': {
        '$lte': -103.4088134765625,
        '$gte': -103.47747802734375
    }
})
```

but if try to query using `geoWithin`, doesn't return me anything

```
db.getCollection('houses').find({
  "coordinates_geojson": {
    "$geoWithin": {
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -103.47747802734375,
                20.458539491985142
              ],
              [
                -103.4088134765625,
                20.458539491985142
              ],
              [
                -103.4088134765625,
                20.49584842128357
              ],
              [
                -103.47747802734375,
                20.49584842128357
              ],
              [
                -103.47747802734375,
                20.458539491985142
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Any help or idea is welcome

Comment: Did you ever build a geospatial index (type `2dsphere` or `2d`) on `coordinates_geojson`? If not, then you need to build the appropriate index in order for geospatial queries to work. More information here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-indexes

Comment: I'm not asking about your document itself, but the `index`. Please make sure that you have a geospatial index built for the `coordinates_geojson` field. Without this index, MongoDB cannot recognize your geoJSON objects and will be unable to perform geospatial queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct answer, first unset the field `coordinates_geojson.deviation_level` and then build the index `db.collection.createIndex({"coordinates_geojson" : "2dsphere" })`.
Thank you @B.Fleming